# Google Analytics API returned User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have run a code followed the instruction below https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'path/to/keyfile'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  "Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ', dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print('Date range:', str(i))
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ':', value)


def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Actually, I can't find View ID on Admin Settings. It just Account and Property. Is it because my property is App + Web and it still Beta? But, when I try to create a new property with App only, it is automatically changed to App + Web.

So confused in the first step trying Google Analytics API.

[image]

Comment: The error means that you have not given the service account access to the account on Google analytics,  go to the admin section and add it under the account level.  If you dont have a view then i suggest you create one.  As far as i know you cant create app only anymore.    App analytics normally uses firebase analytics.

Comment: I have added my service account access to Google Analytics (Admin - under Account User Management and Property User Management).
Have you used Goggle Analytics recently? Firebase Analytics is the same as Google Analytics for now. I connect my apps to fireabse then I integrate it to google or firebase analytics.
How to create View?

Comment: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/d   <-- bottom left hand side.  Firebase analytics.    https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web  <--- google analytics.

Comment: what do you mean with >> As far as i know you cant create app only anymore?

Comment: The google analytics reporting api gives you access to data stored on analytics.google.com.   I am not aware of any api that gives you access to data stored in firebase.google.com    I think you are looking at the wrong api and the wrong website thats why your not finding your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Analytics Data API v1 is the new API for GA4 properties. See the devsite: https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data. The Data API v1 accepts a numeric GA4 property identifiers in report requests.

Firebase show projects. The project ID and number shown in Firebase is not a GA4 Property identifier. To find your GA4 Property identifier:

1. Navigate to the Firebase Analytics Dashboard,
2. select the option "View your data in Google Analytics".
3. In Google Analytics, select "Admin" and "Property Settings".
4. A numeric "PROPERTY ID" will be shown. The Data API v1 accepts this GA4
   Property Id in report request.

App + Web Properties were recently renamed to GA4 Properties. See the blog post: https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new_google_analytics/.

The Google Analytics API v3 (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3) and Google Analytics Reporting API v4 (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) accept numeric view identifiers in report requests.

GA4 Properties do not have views, and there is not a way to create views in those properties.